# Spark and Spark JobServer best practice to avoid of expensive reconstruction objects in each call of runJob(sc: SparkContext, config: Config)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-jobserver

Every-time invoke JobServer runJob API below, I have a time-cost logic to construct an object repeatedly inside the runJob call

```
runJob(sc: SparkContext, config: Config)
```

1. What is the best practice to store the object in memory to avoid repeat construction of the object for every call of runJob API so that each call runJob can reuse the object stored in memory during the first call ?
2. If I can do 1, then can I also remove the object in memory when I need to update the object ?
3. If I can do 1, can I share the object cross cluster ?
4. In addition to regular object, I am also asking what is the best practice to avoid of loading model in each call but just load once, then all following calls can use the model.
5. RDD and DataFrame has similar cache and persist features which I am looking for the regular objects and models. But They requires readFile to be called every time and only operations benifits from cache. One more question is how to avoid of reading file in every call for RDD and DataFrame ?
6. Can Broadcast Variables and Accumulators be used for regular objects and models ?
7. Can Spark JobServer's NamedRddSupport store large objects and models through defining implicit persisters ?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "regular objects and models"?

Comment: regular objects mean arbitrary scala object. Models mean prediction model.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Broadcasts are well suited to your data and Accumulators to your models respectively. I would just add that you may want to look into the functionality provided by `mapPartitions`, which allows you to perform expensive initialization just once per partition.

This is an example from *Learning Spark*:

```
val contactsLists = validSigns.distinct().mapPartitions { signs = > 
  val mapper = createMapper() 
  val client = new HttpClient() 
  client.start() // create http request 
  signs.map { sign => 
    createExchangeForSign(sign) // fetch responses 
  }.map { 
    case (sign, exchange) => (sign, readExchangeCallLog( mapper, exchange)) 
  }.filter( x = > x._2 != null)
}
```

In this example, the `HttpClient` initialization, which is expensive, is done once. Then you use the result to iterate over the partition represented as a `Iterable`.